# How many (Maximum) DB2 multi row fetch cursor can be maintained in PLI/COBOL program?

Tags: db2, mainframe

How many (Maximum) DB2 multi row fetch cursor can be maintained in PLI/COBOL program as part of good performance?

I have a requirement to maintain 4 cursors in PLI program but I am concerned about number of multi fetch cursors in single program.

Is there any other way to check multi row fetch is more effective than normal cursor? I tried with 1000 records but I couldn't see the running time difference.

Answer (score 0):

IBM [published some information](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246465.pdf) (PDF) about multi-row fetch performance when this feature first became available in DB2 8 in 2005.  Their data mentions nothing about the number of cursors in a given program, only the number of rows fetched.

From this I infer the number of multi-row fetch cursors itself is not of concern from a performance standpoint -- within reason.  If someone pushes the limits of reason with 10,000 such cursors I will not be responsible for their anguish.

The IBM Redbook linked to earlier indicates there is a 40% CPU time improvement retrieving 10 rows per fetch, and a 50% CPU time improvement retrieving 100+ rows per fetch.  Caveats:

> The performance improvement using multi-row fetch in general depends
>   on:
>
> - Number of rows fetched in one fetch
> - Number of columns fetched
>     (more improvement with fewer columns), data type and size of the
>     columns
> - Complexity of the fetch. The fixed overhead saved for not
>     having to go between the database engine and the application program
>     has a lower percentage impact for complex SQL that has longer path
>     lengths.
>
> If the multi-row fetch reads more rows per statement, it results in
>   CPU time improvement, but after 10 to 100 rows per multi-row fetch,
>   the benefit is decreased. The benefit decreases because, if the cost
>   of one API overhead per row is 100% in a single row statement, it gets
>   divided by the number of rows processed in one SQL statement. So it
>   becomes 10% with 10 rows, 1% with 100 rows, 0.1% for 1000 rows, and
>   then the benefit becomes negligible.

The Redbook also has some discussion of how they did their testing to arrive at their performance figures.  In short, they varied the number of rows retrieved and reran their program several times, pretty much what you'd expect.